# How to create XMLDocument from jQuery.find() result

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-serialization, xmldocument

I've loaded two XML documents using jQuery's $.ajax() and serialized each to strings, performed a few string manipulations, combined the two strings together, wrapped them in a  node, located child nodes using $.find(), and now want to convert the $.find() result back to an XMLDocument.

A much abbreviated example:

```
$.isXMLDoc(xmlDocument1); // returns true
$.isXMLDoc(xmlDocument2); // returns true

var xml1Str = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDocument1);
var xml2Str = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDocument2);

var xml1And2Str = "<root>" + xml1Str + xml2Str + "</root>";
var xml1And2Doc = $.parseXML(xml1And2Str);
$.isXMLDoc(xml1And2Doc); // returns true

var $oneNode = $(xml1And2Doc).find("oneNodeName");
```

Somewhere inside of xml1And2Doc there is a single xml child-element that looks like `<oneNodeName>...</oneNodeName>`.  The last statement finds that for me and then I can successfully use it, and afterwards, I want to convert it into an XMLDocument.  How can I convert `$oneNode` to an `XMLDocument`?

There are examples that build up to this, but I believe I'm missing something fundamental here about jQuery or the find() results, which bar me from being able to convert that to an XMLDocument.

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/
- http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/working-with-xml-jquery-and-javascript/

Comment: It might be an issue with your xml. I've made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/35A3K/1/) that seems to be working fine.

Comment: I've created a revision of your fiddle document to clarify what I'm trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/35A3K/5/

Comment: I've posted an answer below with an updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/35A3K/6/). After calling `$(xml1And2Doc).find("oneNodeName")` you need to get the first element in the array that jQuery is returning. Here is a snippet:

```
var $oneNode = $(xml1And2Doc).find("oneNodeName")[0]; //finds and selects first object
var aString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($oneNode);
```

jQuery by default returns a collection of DOM elements [see](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery). So accessing the first element is fine with $oneNode[0] but if it's possible for there to be more than one of those elements you could do this:

```
var $oneNodes = $(xml1And2Doc).find("oneNodeName"); //finds set of objects
$.each($oneNodes, function (index) {
    var aString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($oneNodes[index]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks sgarrett, that is clear and concise to me. I will also say, I don't consider myself a jQuery guru.  Is it safe to assume that the result will always be in the first element of the array?  Would this be considered using an "undocumented" technique, such that a revision to jQuery might break our product?

Comment: @MichaelPrescott I have updated the answer with more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you have your XML nodes found with `.find()` you can do the following to convert it to the XML Document:

```
var xmlString  = $('<div>').append($oneNode.clone()).remove().html(),
    oneNodeDoc = $.parseXML(xmlString);
```

So you first convert jQuery element to string (to HTML string) and then apply `$.parseXML` to it.

Comment: Thank you, dfsq.  Is there a more direct way?  I tried both .append() and .prepend() and because my document contains a div in the body, items within that are included in the result string.  I suppose I could have a very specific selector setup just for xml manipulation, like <div id="xmlhandler"/>.  Both seem so cumbersome or fragile.